# Why do some karyotype graphs contain 46 pairs of chromosomes?

Tags: dna, chromosome, karyotype

The human genome consists of 23 pairs of chromosomes. Two copies of each pair connect to each other at the centromere. Normal karyotype graphs should look like this:
[image: normal karyotype]

But some karyotype graphs contain 46 pairs of chromosomes, such as this one: [image: 46 pairs]

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They both contain 23 pairs of homologous chromosomes (and... yes as [Luis](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/54586/luis-sierra) suggested the first one is male and the second one female).

In Figure 1 each chromosome is composed by 1 chromatid, while in Figure 2 each chromosome is composed by 2 chromatids. This is probably because the two pictures were taken at different stages of Mitosis.

In Figure 1 the picture was taken probably in anaphase, while in Figure 2 was probably taken in or before metaphase.

You might want to search the internet to check the **difference between chromatids and chromosomes** and to read something about the **cell cycle and mitosis**.